# How can you tell jQuery to detect arrow key IF it's not in a text/input box

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger some events with the arrow keys IF the cursor isn't in a textbox how can I check with jquery if the cursor is in a textbox?

This is what I have right now

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 37) 
       dosomething();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I did it:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    var isInput = false;
    var activeElement = document.activeElement; // this will get the currently focused dom node
    switch(activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase()){
        case "input":
        case "textarea":
        case "select":
            isInput = true;
    }
    if(!isInput){
        // execute your code here
    }
});
```

If you need support for `contenteditable` elements, you can change your if statement to this:

```
if(!isInput && !activeElement.hasAttribute("contenteditable")){
    // your code
}
```

**EDIT**: To improve readability and remove the switch statement, you can also do something like this instead (although this will only work on relatively modern browsers; Edge 14+).

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    var active = document.activeElement;
    var activeTag = active.tagName.toLowerCase();
    
    var invalidTags = ["input", "textarea", "select"];
    if(!invalidTags.includes(activeTag)){
        // execute your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the textboxes (I'm assuming `<input type="text">`) a class, such as `myClass`. So now you've got:

```
<input type="text" class="myClass">
```

Then you can check with jQuery like this:

```
if (!$( document.activeElement ).hasClass("myClass")
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":input").click(test1);
  function test1() {
    if (!$(document.activeElement).hasClass("myClass")) {
      console.log("Does not have myClass");
    } else {
      console.log("has myClass");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" class="myClass" value="myClass">
 <input type="text" class="myClass" value="myClass">
 <input type="text" class="differentClass" value="differentClass">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well by default the cursor is inside a text box if it has focus, so you could check if a specific text box has focus via `$("..").is(":focus")`.